# Invalid argument error compiling stdio.h / iostream

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[Solved] Switched from the Ubuntu app to the Kali app, and that compiler works fine.

I'm suddenly having trouble compiling anything that includes these header files because of some error from inside the headers. I have never had issues with this before, and I don't even know what the error means. Any help is appreciated!

I am on Windows 10.0.18362 using the Ubuntu app with WSL.

The code is just hello world programs shown below, but when compiled I get the following errors for gcc and g++:

```c
// test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

```cpp
// test.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

```
gcc test.c
In file included from test.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:27:10: fatal error: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h: Invalid argument
 #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

```
g++ test.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:424:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++config.h:533,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:38,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h:427:10: fatal error: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h: Invalid argument
 #include <bits/wordsize.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Check your disk for errors. This looks like a broken hard drive.

Comment: @bryanmodest What is the symbol '%'  doing in this call printf("%Hello, world!\n");?

Comment: this looks **really** strange... did you tweak your system recently somehow? (like installed new version of gcc or some essential libs?) apart from checking your disk as advised above, check also your memory for defects with something like https://www.memtest86.com/

Comment: Use `strace -ocall.log gcc test.c` to compile and paste the stuff *before the message is output to the screen*. I guess something is failing with `EINVAL` error code.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Oh wow, didn't notice! Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I tried that, but I got no extra output before this error.

Comment: @bryanmodest that would log all the system calls into file `call.log`, you'd need to look into *that*. Presumably you should be able to find a call to `write`  with file descriptor 2 and the string `fatal error` there somewhere and then go upwards looking for calls that return `EINVAL`...

Comment: Other than that, I'd `ls -la /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Now I got something: `ls: cannot access '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h': Invalid argument`

Comment: ok, then the next thing: `ls -la /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Also Invalid argument! It got a nice output from /usr/include/

Comment: Yes... you should! Something should show something... I guess you have a disk corruption.

Comment: I got this: `drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    512 May 13  2019 x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: Are you using WSL by any chance?  The same issue is reported here:  https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3204 and https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1735.  I suggest that you check for updates to both WSL and your Linux distro within WSL.  Either way you should describe your environment/platform - it may be relevant.

Comment: @Clifford Yes I am, I'll go research these links. Thank you!!

Comment: That's why it is absolutely mandatory to describe the system you're using. Please edit your question and add all this info!

Comment: I've added the tag, but you should in any case mention it in the question.  Also hone your Google Fu.  I searched "_gnu preprocessor  "invalid argument"_" to find those threads.

Comment: `%H` in format string causes undefined behaviour

Comment: I have edited out the % sign in the c program to avoid confusion